# When using an UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout, is there a way to have a custom size for only certain items in the datasource?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

Say you're using a completely typical layout:

```
let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { (_, _) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection? in
    let layoutSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
        widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1/CGFloat(3)),
        heightDimension: .absolute(rowHeight)
    )
    let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: layoutSize)

    let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
        widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
        heightDimension: .absolute(rowHeight)
    )
    let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [item])

    return NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
}
```

So that is a 3<sup>†</sup> column layout:

[image]

However, occasionally there's an item in the section (and there's only one section) that is full width (or perhaps any specific size):

```
if daData[indexPath.item].whatever = .special { ...
```

[image]

#### Solutions could be something like ...

#### (A) ...

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
      layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
      sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
   if .. return .. the default from the compositional layout
   else .. return some specific size
```

But I believe that's not possible / I don't know how to return the "super" of `#sizeForItemAt` (and I don't know if that would indeed be the value from the compositional layout).

#### (B) ...

```
let layoutSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
  widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1/  item == 666 ? 1 : 3 ),
```

but I don't know how to **use the indexPath inside compositional layout** (you can use the section but not the index path, as far as I know)

#### (C) ...

```
    widthDimension: estimated: .fractionalWidth(1/3),
    ...
    groupSize .. similar idea
```

But I don't know how to **set the width as both estimated and fractional**.

Perhaps combined with `#sizeForItemAt`, but I don't know how to combine a column number compositional layout with estimated sizes with `#sizeForItemAt`

Is there a way?

In short ideally:

- most items would have a width creating two columns, but,
- based on the datasource, the occasional item would have a one-column width.

---

*footnotes*

<sup>†</sup> In practice you have to deal with rotation (or other animating shapes). You can do this amazingly elegantly in compositional layout ...

```
// let columnCount = self.bounds.width < self.bounds.height ? CGFloat(2) : CGFloat(3)
// more specifically, often best to use the whole screen ... in case of for example a slide-up panel
var columnCount = CGFloat(2)
if let glass = self.findViewController()?.view.bounds {
    if glass.width > glass.height {
        columnCount = CGFloat(3)
    }
}

let layoutSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
    widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1/columnCount), .. etc
```

remembering to

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    collection.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout() // for rotation changes
}
```

Comment: What about using `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` instead of `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout`?

Comment: It could well be; I'm just not sure of the top of my head if flow layout is good at doing N columns.  The `widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1/CGFloat(3))` aspect of compositional layout is so critical.  (I have it change number of columns when portrait/landscape - works out wonderfully.)

Comment: Indeed someone asked this *Is there an equivalent to sizeForItemAt IndexPath but for UICollectionviewCompositionalLayout* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72744669  which is my "A" but there's no coherent answer yet :/

Comment: Would https://lickability.com/blog/getting-started-with-uicollectionviewcompositionallayout/ help?

Comment: pervy domain name!! :)  @VonC , that's a great intro, love the link, thanks.  But if I'm  not mistaken it doesn't touch on a solution to the "custom for some items" issue .. sadly ..

Comment: @Fattie Does the accepted solution have to use `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout` or is a solution that uses `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` to give a column layout (except for the exceptionally sized items of course) be fine?

Comment: @HangarRash I would say that, since (apparently) it is an intractable problem with the constraint ".. using `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout`". imo an answer which shows how it can be done with a flow layout would certainly be very welcome indeed. (For me a huge advantage of Compositional is the elegant `item.contentInsets` and the priceless `.fractionalWidth` {added a footnote about this wonderous stuff}, I just don't know if that can be handled as easily in a flow layout.)

Comment: You could simply write your _own_ layout. That is the whole point of UICollectionView: you are not tied to flow layout or to compositional layout, you can simply roll your own and do anything you like.

Comment: @matt - absolutely, I think i mention that. (I do that as a matter of course for many cases, whenever it is an "unusual" layouts.)  However, I put it to you that for "fixed column" layouts (see my pink images), `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout` is God's gift. Just as it would be poor engineering to write a sort in current Swift, you'd surely use that available tech. Now, the issue is, if you glance at my three points "A, B, C" ... if someone **decisively knows** if indeed (all three!) of those are *not possible* - then it's answered.  I must have spent 4h investigating "C" and no dice

Comment: Regarding "A" it seems to be a long-standing question. It *seems*  to be that as soon as you use * fractionalWidth* it is no longer possible to do that individually.  Regarding "B" I simply couldn't find out (after an hour) if you can use the indexPath inside compositional layout - there's only so much time in the day you know? (I assumed someone would pop on here, or the many related questions already asked, and state "that's right, it's impossible to do that", but not yet!)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a reasonably straightforward approach that uses `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`. This sample lets you show cells in a fixed number of columns but allows some items to be shown full width.

The trick to showing cells in fixed columns with a flow layout is calculating the proper item size. The calculated width needs to take into account the collection view's width, the safe area insets, the section insets, and the iter-item spacing between cells in a row.

Comments in the code provide more details.

```swift
// Dummy data structure
struct ItemData {
    let isFullSize: Bool
}

class ViewController: UICollectionViewController {
    let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = .init()

    var data = [ItemData]()
    let columns = 3
    let rowHeight: CGFloat = 75
    var columnWidth: CGFloat = 0.0
    var fullWidth: CGFloat = 0.0

    init() {
        // Setup the layout as desired
        layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 10
        layout.sectionInset = .init(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 10)
        layout.sectionInsetReference = .fromSafeArea

        super.init(collectionViewLayout: layout)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")

        // Generate data where one specific item is shown full size
        data = Array(repeating: ItemData(isFullSize: false), count: 18)
        data[5] = ItemData(isFullSize: true)
    }

    private func updateSizes(for size: CGSize) {
        // Account for the view's safeAreaInsets and the layout's sectionInsets
        let cvWidth: CGFloat = size.width - view.safeAreaInsets.left - view.safeAreaInsets.right - layout.sectionInset.left - layout.sectionInset.right
        fullWidth = cvWidth.rounded(.towardZero)
        // Account for the layout's minimumInteritemSpacing
        columnWidth = ((fullWidth - layout.minimumInteritemSpacing * CGFloat(columns - 1)) / CGFloat(columns)).rounded(.towardZero)

        self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
    }

    // Adjust for updates to the safe area
    override func viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange() {
        super.viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange()

        updateSizes(for: view.bounds.size)
    }

    // Adjust for initial display
    override func viewIsAppearing(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewIsAppearing(animated)

        updateSizes(for: view.bounds.size)
    }

    // Adjust for device rotation or iPad split screen
    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: any UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

        updateSizes(for: size)
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        // Show a trivial green square for each cell
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        cell.backgroundColor = .green

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        // Set the item's width based on whether it's full size or not
        let item = data[indexPath.row]
        if item.isFullSize {
            return CGSize(width: fullWidth, height: rowHeight)
        } else {
            return CGSize(width: columnWidth, height: rowHeight)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

As you can see, there is one arguable "flaw" with this use of a flow layout - rows that have only 1 or 2 cells don't keep those cells aligned to the left. This is solved by subclassing `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and using the subclass.

See [Left Align Cells in UICollectionView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22539979/left-align-cells-in-uicollectionview) for lots of solutions. The following example is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58436679/20287183):

```swift
class LeftAlignedFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        guard let att = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in:rect) else {return []}
        var x: CGFloat = sectionInset.left
        var y: CGFloat = -1.0

        for a in att {
            if a.representedElementCategory != .cell { continue }

            if a.frame.origin.y >= y { x = sectionInset.left }
            a.frame.origin.x = x
            x += a.frame.width + minimumInteritemSpacing
            y = a.frame.maxY
        }
        return att
    }
}
```

Change:

```
let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = .init()
```

to:

```
let layout: LeftAlignedFlowLayout = .init()
```

and now you get:

[image]

Comment: Good one. I love the correct and elegant `viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange` etc overrides.  This is a sad reminder that FlowLayout doesn't really do much and you have to do everything upstream heh!!

Comment: A hard-earned bounty!  :O  I'm gonna leave this mystery question unticked since, so far no-one has been able to answer the specific questions A/B/C about compositional layout, so it will give future people a chance.